# Missing RouteData DataTokens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, routedata

I'm handling errors in ASP.NET MVC by sending an error id from Application.OnError to a controller action, by adding a route data value that gives the error id:

Global.asax.cs/OnError:

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.DataTokens.Add("errorKey", errorId);
var context = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
errorController.Execute(context);
```

And then reading it in the controller/action:

```
object errorKey = RouteData.DataTokens["errorKey"];
```

On my local machine it runs fine, but on the servers I have tried the errorKey is not passed along.

What could be possible reasons for this?

---

A new observation, when the site is running a web server:

- If I visit from a browser on the web server itself, the route data is transferred alright
- If I visit from another machine, the route data is *not* transferred

Comment: have you looked in the RouteData.Values["errorKey"] to see if your data was there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason:
In web.config was set the following:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
```

which caused the action to be executed twice: the first time *with* the errorKey, but the second and deciding time *without* the errorKey.
I changed it to

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
```

and the action was only executed once, *with* the errorKey.

Answer (score 2):

i've never tried to use the route data in such a way, you might want to look into this instead

HttpContext.Items["errorKey"]

the items are scoped to your request.

you may also want to look at TempData["errorKey"] found on the controller :

[ASP.NET TempData persists between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473520/asp-net-tempdata-persists-between-requests/473569#473569)

as for the values in the route data, have a look at  **RouteData.Values["errorKey"]**

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful, but didn't change the behavior.