# MVC3 RedirectToAction in a post method and ViewBag suppression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

i'm currently working a list of data that i need to display in a view that represent a list and show for each item the corresponding action that can be executed, like edit them or delete them. For the edition there is no problem concedering that it's a particular view. My problem is when i want to delete an item, i have two choices in the post method.

```
 //Call directly the list 
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult Delete(int itemId)
 {
     // logic to delete an item
     ViewBag.Error = ""; // The result of the execution
     return List(); 
 }
```

The thing with this solution is that the url is no longer the same as the first one : .../List, it's .../Delete now, i don't find this solution great, the other solution is to redirect to the action, now the url is good, but the error message in the viewBag is no longer visible, Do you guys have some better idea.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `TempData` to persist information across one request and it was meant for this exact use case. Rather than use the `ViewBag` use `TempData["Error"] = "";` instead. Then, on the receiving end you would have a snippet like the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult List() {
    ViewBag.Error = TempData["Error"];
    // ...
    return View();
}
```

See [ASP.NET TempData persists between requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473520) and [When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.Net MVC 3](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications).

Comment: Nice suggestion to set ViewBag.Error = TempData["Error"] in the controller, so that the view need not be concerned about this detail.

Comment: Yeah, I used to have it in the view itself, but then I had a lot of logic in the view dealing with which variable to look at. I use the controller to grab all the information necessary and pass it to the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua for the answer, it works fine, and thanks for the reading resources too.

Answer (score 13):

If you are doing a redirect, try using `TempData` instead of `ViewBag`. TempData is a dictionary that preserves keys/values in the user's session until the next page request. In your controller:

```
TempData["Error"] = "A message goes here";
```

In your List view that you are redirecting to:

```
@TempData["Error"]
```

Or if you are not using razor:

```
<%= TempData["Error"] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ViewBag` to POST `ActionResult`:

```
ActionResult SubmitUser()
{
    ViewBag.Msg =TempData["Msg"];

    return view();
}

[HtttpPost]
ActionResult SubmitUser()
{
    TempData["Msg"] ="Submitted Successfully"];

    return view();
}
```