# Enter 3 dates and display order in different VIEW, after click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-parsing

Hey guys so im attempting to throw a project together to increase my knowledge of MVC3 but I have hit a wall...

So from my HolidaysController inside my index 'view' I have created a hyperlink which will navigate the user to the 'create3' ActionResult

@Html.ActionLink("Select 3 Dates", "Create3")

---

In my create3 page I want the user to enter 3 dates into text boxes and when they click 'create' the user will be returned to the previous HolidaysController/Index page
where the dates will be displayed in order of ascending date

....ATM I have this working up until the user enters 3 dates and clicks 'create'...However I only know how to display a message box displaying the order, it is working I just need help getting the order to be displayed from the index page.

Please see my code:

### Code for HolidayController/Index:

```
 //submit will go to post
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(int HolidayDate)
        {
            var holidays = db.Holidays.Include("Person");

            HolidayList model = new HolidayList();

            model.currentPersonID = HolidayDate;
            model.PList4DD = db.People.ToList();           
            model.Categories = holidays.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                                Text = x.Person.Name
                                            }
                                          );


            int data = HolidayDate;

            model.HList4DD = db.Holidays.Where(h => h.PersonId == HolidayDate).ToList();      

            return View(model);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, int? currentPersonID)
        {
            var holidays = db.Holidays.Include("Person");

            HolidayList model = new HolidayList();

            //not null
            if (currentPersonID.HasValue)
            {
                model.currentPersonID = currentPersonID.Value;

            }
            else
            {
                model.currentPersonID = 0;
            }

            model.PList4DD = db.People.ToList();

            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "date" : "";
            var dates = from d in db.Holidays
                        where d.PersonId == currentPersonID.Value
                        select d;

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "date":
                    dates = dates.OrderBy(p => p.HolidayDate);
                    break;
            }

            model.HList4DD = dates.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```

---

```
//View for Index

@*@model IEnumerable<HolidayBookingApp.Models.Holiday>*@
@model HolidayBookingApp.Models.HolidayList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Select 3 Dates", "Create3")
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            PersonId
        </th>
        <th>
            @*HolidayDate*@
            @Html.ActionLink("HolidayDate", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentPersonID = Model.currentPersonID })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.HList4DD)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HolidayDate)

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>}

    <tr>
      <div class="editor-label">
         @*   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PList4DD, "Person")*@
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">           
             &lt;form action ="/Holidays/Index" id="some" method="post"> 

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HList4DD.First().HolidayDate, new SelectList(Model.PList4DD, "Id", "Name", Model.currentPersonID), "--select--")    
       &lt;script>
           function updateFormEnabled() 
           {
               if (verifyAdSettings()) 
               {
                   $('#sbmt').removeAttr('disabled');
               }
               else 
               {
                   $('#sbmt').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               }
           }

           function verifyAdSettings() 
           {
               if ($('#HolidayDate').val() != '') 
               {
                   return true;
               }
               else 
               {
                   return false;
               }
           }

           $('#HolidayDate').change(updateFormEnabled);

           &lt;/script>

             &lt;input type="submit" id= "sbmt" name="ViewHolidaysDD" value="View"/>
              &lt;/form>
  &lt;script>
      $('#sbmt').attr('disabled', '');
        &lt;/script>

        </div>

</table>

<br />
<br />
<table>
    <div>
    Judging by your selection the order of dates are: //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE ORDER OF DATES
    </div>

</table>
```

### Just above is where I want to display my dates in order, ascending

```
//my create 3 Action result


 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create3()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create3(string date1, string date2, string date3)
        {
            string FirstDateOrder, SecondDateOrder, ThirdDateOrder;

            //date 1 is biggest
            if (date1.Length > date2.Length && date1.Length > date3.Length)
            {
                //date 2 is 2nd & date 3 is 3rd
                if (date2.Length > date3.Length)
                {
                    FirstDateOrder = date1;
                    SecondDateOrder = date2;
                    ThirdDateOrder = date3;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 1, 2, 3");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                //date 3 is 2nd & date 2 is 3rd
                else
                {
                    FirstDateOrder = date1;
                    SecondDateOrder = date3;
                    ThirdDateOrder = date2;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 1, 3, 2");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }

            //date 2 is biggest
            if (date2.Length > date1.Length && date2.Length > date3.Length)
            {
                //date 1 is 2nd & date 3 is 3rd
                if (date1.Length > date3.Length)
                {
                    FirstDateOrder = date2;
                    SecondDateOrder = date1;
                    ThirdDateOrder = date3;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 2, 1, 3");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                //date 3 is 2nd & date 1 is 3rd
                else
                {
                    FirstDateOrder = date2;
                    SecondDateOrder = date3;
                    ThirdDateOrder = date1;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 2, 3, 1");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }

            //date 3 is biggest
            if (date3.Length > date1.Length && date3.Length > date2.Length)
            {
                //date 1 is 2nd & date 2 is 3rd
                if (date1.Length > date2.Length)
                {
                    FirstDateOrder = date3;
                    SecondDateOrder = date1;
                    ThirdDateOrder = date2;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 3, 1, 2");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                //date 2 is 2nd & date 1 is 3rd
                else
                {
                    FirstDateOrder = date3;
                    SecondDateOrder = date2;
                    ThirdDateOrder = date1;

                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 3, 2, 1");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

### }

```
and my view:

    @model HolidayBookingApp.Models.Dates

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create3";
}

<h2>Create3</h2>

&lt;script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">&lt;/script>
&lt;script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript">&lt;/script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dates</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date3)
        </div>

        <p>
            &lt;input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>"Index")


</div>
```

---

Not sure where to go from here something like create a paramter in the Index View which pulls across the order?

Any help would be great thanks guys and sorry about the essay

Comment: Yeah sorry about that Shai...haven't been online all weekend only catching up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other more elegant ways of doing this, but probably the easiest is the use of ViewBag.  Rather than:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Order is 3, 1, 2");
```

Try something like this:

```
ViewBag.DateOrder = "Order is 3, 1, 2";
```

Then in your View simply put:

```
<span>@ViewBag.DateOrder</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for that jmrnet...it was a great help

Comment: Although one Q...This works if I run it through the same method, However I tried to do the ViewBag.DateOrder = "Order is 3, 1, 2"; in my actionResult create3 method, and run <span>@ViewBag.DateOrder</span> from the view of actionResult index(), this however did not pick up, did it delete the record when it loaded a different page? Possibly the re direct to is to blame?                                                      return RedirectToAction("Index");

Comment: True.  The redirect does kill the viewbag contents.  Instead, try using TempData with the viewbag as described in this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124277/mvc3-redirecttoaction-in-a-post-method-and-viewbag-suppression